# Why doesn't Google Maps show my home and the starred locations while planning a route?

Tags: google-chrome, google-maps

Is there any way to switch [it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PxKu.jpg) back on? Now the starring function seems useless.

Comment: Are you logged in?

Comment: Yes, I am logged in.

Comment: @pnuts No, I have all my cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by enabling google history...